# How to obtain the exponent value of a number?

Tags: swift, exponent

Basically I would like to know if it is possible to get the exponent value in a number, ex:

number = 2.6e3

I want to get the value 3 of the exponent. I have been searching for quite a while now and have not found the answer to this. I am new to programming so I may not know exactly what to look for (which methods, etc).

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your problem lies in mathematics. If you have an unknown base and an unknown exponent, it is impossible to find either.

Comment: `let exp = floor(log10(number))`

Comment: Your wording implies your looking for an exponent, but your examples implies you're looking for an order of magnitude. In the latter case @vacawama example will work.

Comment: Thank you vacawama, the sis exactly what I wanted!! Jjatie, please read my comment in Alex answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your question: Given a number as an integer, find the interger value of the log base 10 of it.

```
import Foundation
func log(Int number) -> Int
{
    return floor(log10(number))
}
```

Comment: Thank you orccrusher99, this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly this is what you want to do:
B = A^X where A and B are known values.  Solve for X.

1000 = 10^X  (In this case, X = 3.)

The below code will work for any base.  It requires either Foundation or UIKit.  The function arguments "value" and "base" are B, A respectively. Try the code out in the Xcode Playground!

```
func getExponentForValueAndBase(value: Double, base: Double) -> Double {
    return log(value)/log(base)
}

getExponentForValueAndBase(1000, base: 10) // = 3
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, however vacawama and orccrusher99 understood exactly what it is that I wanted. I apologize to all for my poor explanation, however that was exactly my problem, I couldn't find the correct way to express what I wanted. But this is still great and I will definitely keep this snippet you provided handy! :D